# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘start’ when I inherit std::vector

Tags: c++

here is my code, it raise error in `vector<ET>(iterator start, iterator end)`

```
namespace ro {
    template<typename ET>
    class vector : public std::vector<ET> {
    public:
        vector<ET>() : std::vector<ET>() { }
        vector<ET>(std::initializer_list<ET> l) : std::vector<ET>(l) { }
        using std::vector<ET>::iterator;
        vector<ET>(iterator start, iterator end) : std::vector<ET>(start, end) { }
    };
}
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    ro::vector<int> v{1, 2};
    return (0);
};
```

the full error output:

```
/home/roroco/Dropbox/cs/ro-c/ex/ex.cc:15:29: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘start’
         vector<ET>(iterator start, iterator end) : std::vector<ET>(start, end) { }
```

how to make it work?

Comment: Is this example really minimal? Where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I think the example is small and clear enough along with the exact error message. As per error message error occurs in line `vector<ET>(iterator start, iterator end) : std::vector<ET>(start, end) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `using std::vector<ET>::iterator;` with

```
using typename std::vector<ET>::iterator;
//    ^^^^^^^^
```

Without `typename` compiler has no way to determine whether `iterator` is a member field/function or type. So compiler assumes it is a field/function.